# Tangent space chart dependent or not?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I was wondering whether the definition of a tangent space is chart dependent or not? Cause to me it seems that they depend on the charts:

Let $p \in M$ where $M$ is a k-dim smooth manifold and $\phi: U(p) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ a chart where $U(p)$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$ in $M$. Then according to our definition of the tangent space, this one is a space spanned by the directional derivatives $D_v|_p:=\sum_{i=1}^k v_i D_i|_p.$ Now $D_i|_p(f):=D_i(f\circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))$ is just defined as the partial derivative in $\mathbb{R}^k$ ($f \in C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$) via the chart and this is why I guess that the definition of this tangent space, i.e. its basis $\{D_i|_p;i \in \{1,..,k\}\}$ depends on the chart.

If this is true, then also the dual basis (the differential forms ) $dx^i|_p(D_j|_p):= \delta^i_j$ are depedent on the chart and not globally defined on the manifold. Is this correct?

Comment: The basis may depend on the chart, but the vector space that they span is not.

Comment: @WSL what do you exactly mean by this?  I mean it is clear that the vector spaces must be isomorphic, because they have the same dimension. But are you saying that $f \mapsto D_i( f\circ \psi^{-1})(\psi(p)) \in T_pM$ with respect to the chart $\psi$ defined on a neighbourhood of $p$ is also an element of $T_pM$ defined via the  chart $\phi$ defined on a neighbourhood of $p$?

Comment: @RealAnalysis: The question in your title ("Does the tangent space depend on a chart?" Answer: No.) does not match that in the body ("Do the coordinate vector fields, i.e., a basis for the tangent space, depend on a chart?" Answer: Yes.) :)